# Error in creating a dynamic jqGrid , ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

First, I would like to tell that i am new on the .net development (MVC 4)
and I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2010/07/10/asp-net-mvc-and-a-generic-jqquery-grid-jqtgrid-part-3/)  with entity framework 5 but I keep getting this error " **exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in jqGridMVC2.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
, even though i tried to cheeck the value for null before.

```
if(propInfo.GetValue(this, null) != null) {
    }



 private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string property)
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property);

    //    if (obj != null)
    //       if (propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) != null)
          return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);

    //   return 0;
    }



at jqGridMVC2.Extensions.GridExtension.GetPropertyValue(Object obj, String property) in c:\Users\aal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\jqGridMVC2\jqGridMVC2\Extensions\Grid\GridExtension.cs:line 70
   at jqGridMVC2.Extensions.GridExtension.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.<AsJqGridResult>b__2(T item) in c:\Users\aal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\jqGridMVC2\jqGridMVC2\Extensions\Grid\GridExtension.cs:line 38
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SkipIterator>d__4d`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<TakeIterator>d__3a`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at jqGridMVC2.Extensions.GridExtension.AsJqGridResult[T](IQueryable`1 source, String column, String sortOrder, Int32 page, Int32 pageSize) in c:\Users\aal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\jqGridMVC2\jqGridMVC2\Extensions\Grid\GridExtension.cs:line 41
   at jqGridMVC2.Controllers.HomeController.DynamicGridData(String sidx, String sord, Int32 page, Int32 rows) in c:\Users\aal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\jqGridMVC2\jqGridMVC2\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 30
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
```

**Please help me in solving this problem**
*Thank you in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve the error by this

```
private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string property)
{
    foreach (var property1 in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
        return property1.GetValue(obj, null); //throws exception TargetParameterCountException for String type
    }
    return 0;
}
```